# nasm "error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand"

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm on Debian 9. These are the errors:

```
andrea@debian:~/Assembly/sandbox$ nasm -f elf -g -F stabs sandbox.asm
sandbox.asm:8: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
sandbox.asm:9: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
sandbox.asm:11: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
sandbox.asm:12: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

This is the code:

```
section .data
section .text

global _start

_start:
    nop
    mov eax 10
    mov ebx 12

    mov eax 1
    mov ebx 0
    int 80H
    nop

section .bss
```

What's the problem causing these errors and how can I fix it?

If I use the following code where I fix the commas between operands I get a different error:

```
section .data
section .text

    global_start

_start:
    nop
    mov eax,10
    mov ebx,12

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80H
    nop

section .bss
```

The error I get is:

```
sandbox.asm:4: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: In the code You described as "correct", there is `global_start`, which seems incorrect. As I wrote in my answer, it rather should be `global _start`. After this correction, do You get the same set of errors when trying to compile the code?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose there is a space missing and it should be:

```
global _start
```

in line 4.

I also suspected that the hexadecimal constant may be in incorrect format, because of missing `0` prefix, but it should be ok as long as the number starts with a digit, as *Michael Petch* mentioned in the comments (and according to the documentation of NASM available here: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html).

Comment: My mistake, I posted the new code, the old one lacked commas after the mnemonics.sorry.global _start was in error too.

Comment: There is no need to put an extra zero in front of this `int 080h`. `int 80h` is fine. You only need to put the leading zero at the beginning if the first digit is not between 0 and 9. If the number had been A0 hex it would have to be `0A0h` because the hex digit A is not between 0 and 9.

Comment: @Andrea Then please edit the question so it shows your actual code! Use copy/paste to copy the actual code you tried to assemble, don't give us anything else.